# Unable to add style to projected content in Angular 4

Tags: css, angular

I have created a modal component that projects 3 sections: header, body and footer.

`modal.component.html`

```
<div>
    <ng-content select="section[modal-header]"></ng-content>
    <ng-content select="section[modal-body]"></ng-content>
    <ng-content select="section[modal-footer]"></ng-content>
</div>
```

Thus, usage:

```
<modal-component>
    <section modal-header>Header</section>
    <section modal-body>Body</section>
    <section modal-footer>Footer</section>
</modal-component>
```

I want to style the `header`. Thus:

```
modal.component.scss

:host([modal-header]) { font-weight: bold; }
```

This doesn't work. Am I missing anything?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Component styles normally apply only to the HTML in the component's own template.

Use the /deep/ shadow-piercing descendant combinator to force a style down through the child component tree into all the child component views. The /deep/ combinator works to any depth of nested components, and it applies to both the view children and content children of the component.

```
:host /deep/ [modal-header] { font-weight: bold; }
```

In angular documentation they mention that /deep/ is deprecated so you can use
::ng-deep

```
:host ::ng-deep [modal-header] { font-weight: bold; }
```

> The shadow-piercing descendant combinator is deprecated and support is
> being removed from major browsers and tools. As such we plan to drop
> support in Angular (for all 3 of /deep/, >>> and ::ng-deep). **Until
> then ::ng-deep should be preferred for a broader compatibility with
> the tools**.

[Component Styles](https://angular.io/guide/component-styles)

[**stackblitz demo**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ng-deep-example)

Comment: It's being deprecated, what should we do instead?

Comment: As it is deprecated, the answer from @Saksham should be used

Comment: @AdamMarshalyes that true but until now nothing mention at the angular documentation about the correct why to change some child component style from the current component,setting the `ViewEncapsulation.None` is not the answer sometime use use some third party component and we cant change the ViewEncapsulation option.

Answer (score 7):

Quoting from the official Angular documentation

> The shadow-piercing descendant combinator is deprecated and support is
>   being removed from major browsers and tools. As such we plan to drop
>   support in Angular (for all 3 of /deep/, >>> and ::ng-deep).

The other alternative could be to use the `@Component` decorators `encapsulation` property in a combination with adding a class to the host using `@HostBinding`

1. Set child component's `encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None`. This will make sure that there is no style encapsulation and the styles are valid globally.
2. To encapsulate the styles, add a custon CSS class to the host of the child component as

   ```
   @HostBinding('class.custContainerClass') containerClass: boolean = true;
   ```
3. Write your styles in the child component as

   ```
   .custContainerClass .projectedElement { }
   ```

Demo at: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-add-styles-to-projected-content

Comment: This works perfectly and should be the accepted answer

Comment: what if I use third party component and I cant set the `ViewEncapsulation.None`

Comment: @malbarmawi Set it to `Native` in the parent component

Comment: @Saksham what gone to happen in case of native the emulator meantto act like native  , because not all browser support native until now I don't found a link to tell we can now switch to native , can you verify you answer by add an example

Answer (score -1):

I think you should add css in component where your are using `modal-component`

like if you are using `modal-component` in `app.component.html` then you should write css in `app.component.scss` without **host** and **ng deep**

```
[modal-header] {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

actually it has 2 reasons, 1 because there might be change that you are using `modal-component` in two different component and want different css for sections.

and second is that you should write css where actual content is.

and if you still want to write css code in your `modal-component` then you should create parent container to hold that content like:

```
<div class="header">
  <ng-content select="section[modal-header]"></ng-content>
</div>
<ng-content select="section[modal-body]"></ng-content>
<ng-content select="section[modal-footer]"></ng-content>
```

and in your `modal.component.scss` file

```
.header {
  font-weight: bold
 }
```

because `ng-content` is replaced with new template so you need parent container.